# sums return String, only with postgresql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am migrating a database from mysql to postgres. The migration itself was ok, following the postgres documentation.

Right now, I'm fixing our specific mysql queries.

In some point, we have now something like this:

```
select(%(
  SUM(CASE WHEN income THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS rents,
  SUM(CASE WHEN not income THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS expenses
))
```

In mysql, it was a `sum(if(incomes, value, 0))` etc, and it was working as expected.

With PG, it returns a string instead of a numeric.

I already checked the database and the data type is correct.

What can I do, besides cast `to_d` or `to_f`?

---

**EDIT**: the complete query:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN income THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS rents,
 SUM(CASE WHEN not income THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS expenses
 FROM "transactions"
 WHERE "transactions"."type" IN ('Transaction')
 AND "transactions"."user_id" = 1
 AND "transactions"."paid" = 't'
 AND (transactions.date between '2013-09-01' and '2013-09-30')
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is data type for `value`?

Comment: @mvp: Doesn't matter, `Model.select('1 as x').first.x.class` says `String` too.

Comment: Datatype of `value` in database is numeric.

Comment: What do `Model.select('1 as x').first.x.class` and `Model.select("'1' as x").first.x.class` say with MySQL? I'd check myself but I don't have any Rails/MySQL apps set up.

Comment: Now I'm in work, but as far as I can remember, it's BigDecimal.

Comment: If `value` is numeric, there is no way PostgreSQL would return string for such expression. Could you show the real query?

Comment: Yes, one minute please, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Updated, in case you didn't seen it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, using `.to_f`, `.to_i` or whatever is the answer - the Rails PostGres adapter seems adamant that everything is a String unless it's an ActiveRecord model.

See: [connection.select_value only returns strings in postgres with pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571215/connection-select-value-only-returns-strings-in-postgres-with-pg-gem)

I don't particularly approve of this, but it is, as the saying goes, 'working as intended'.

Comment: Yes, definitely a PostgreSQL activerecord issue rather than the database itself.

Comment: You could do things like `Model.select(...).each { |m| def m.x; attributes['x'].to_i; end }` if desired.

Comment: that's basically what I did... but, it feels wrong... Thanks anyway.