# How to get interval results from postgresql as integers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

I am running a query in rails to get the delay between two events in minutes. I have this working nicely as follows;

```
orders.select("extract(epoch from (orders.procedure_time - orders.call_time)) / 60 AS delay").map &:delay
```

where orders is an existing ActiveRecord::Relation object

This works absolutely fine so far except that what I get back is an array of strings rather than integers. It's easy enough to sort out in Ruby - what I have done is the following;

```
orders.select("extract(epoch from (orders.procedure_time - orders.call_time)) / 60 AS delay").map{|x| x.delay.to_i}
```

This will do, but I am just wondering if there is a way to get the integers directly from postgres? It seems like it must have the integers initially, but they are being converted to strings which I then have to convert back, which has a whiff of inelegance about it.

Comment: I guess the pgsql driver is converting the integers to strings. Can you try to execute `"select 1::int as id;"` and see what is the type of the returned result?

Comment: @AntoanMilkov: Anything that isn't a table column will come out as a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sums return String, only with postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754007/sums-return-string-only-with-postgresql) or at least this is another face of the same underlying problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. It looks like there's no other way then.