# Rails hash key/value created differently in local vs heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, hash

I ran into this issue late last night and I just figured out what happened, but I want to understand why. I tested my code in my local (using sqlite) and it worked fine, but when I deployed to heroku (postgres), a summary table was not showing the right results. The summary data is being retrieved from a hash that is created by querying active record, converting to row and then to hash, resulting in a key, value pair hash, let's call that @assignments. The method used to create that result is the following:

```
 def summarize_hrs(date,userid)
    @query = "SELECT id, (coalesce(hrs1,0) + coalesce(hrs2,0) + coalesce(hrs3,0)) as hrs
                        FROM
                        ((
                            (
                            jobs
                            left outer join
                            (SELECT job1, sum(coalesce(hrs1,0)) as hrs1 FROM schedules WHERE date = '" + date.to_s + "' and job1 is not null and user_id =" + userid.to_s + " group by job1) s1
                            on jobs.id = s1.job1
                            ) sum1
                        left outer join
                                (SELECT job2, sum(coalesce(hrs2,0)) as hrs2 FROM schedules WHERE date = '" + date.to_s + "' and job2 is not null and user_id =" + userid.to_s + " group by job2) s2
                                on sum1.id = s2.job2) sum2
                             left outer join
                            (SELECT job3, sum(coalesce(hrs3,0)) as hrs3 FROM schedules WHERE date = '" + date.to_s + "' and job3 is not null and user_id =" + userid.to_s + " group by job3) s3
                            on sum2.id = s3.job3)"
    @assignments = Hash[Schedule.connection.select_all(@query).rows]    
    return @assignments     
  end
```

As a troubleshooting step I started printing the @assignment contents to the screen and this is what I got:

local (sqlite): {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>9.0, 4=>0, 5=>0} 
prod (heroku): {"1"=>"11", "2"=>"7", "3"=>"0", "4"=>"7"}

The results are for different users thus they are not going to match; however what's interesting is that the heroku hash has "" and the local one does not. Why is this, is there anything I'm doing wrong in the query/conversion.

On the interim I've fixed this by forcing my prod key to be a string (shown below), but this breaks my local. Any help will be much appreciated

```
 </tr>
      <% @total_planned = 0 %>
      <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
      <% @search = "Select "+ @col+" FROM schedule_plans where job_id= "+job.id.to_s+" and user_id = "+@userid.to_s 
       @scheduled_hrs = SchedulePlan.connection.select_value(@search).to_f  %>
      <tr>
        <% if (@scheduled_hrs > 0) %>
        <% @total_planned = @total_planned + @scheduled_hrs %>
        <% @assigned_hrs = @assignments[job.id.to_s].to_f %>
        <td> <%= job.name %> </td>
        <td> <%= @assigned_hrs %> </td>
        <td> <%= @scheduled_hrs %> </td>
        <td class = "variance" > <%= @scheduled_hrs - @assigned_hrs%></td>
        <%end%>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a difference in how the `pg` Gem and underlying `libpq` driver handle typing vs. the SQLite driver, stemming from a deliberate decision by the driver developers to leave type conversion to the application framework and return everything as a string. By executing raw SQL and going straight from `Result.rows` to `Hash` you are by-passing logic in ActiveRecord to map types, so you get the type chosen by the driver.

See:

- [connection.select_value only returns strings in postgres with pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571215/connection-select-value-only-returns-strings-in-postgres-with-pg-gem)
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Driver_development#Type_Conversions

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. Do you have any thoughts on how to not bypass the ActiveRecord logic to map types? AciveRecordResult.to_hash returned something that wasn't what I was looking for since it included column names as the key.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to that (my knowledge of Rails is fairly weak). What I did come up with was something like this: `@assignments = rst.rows.collect {|k,v| {k.to_i => v.to_i}}` where `rst` is the result from `Schedule.connection.select_all(@query)`. It adds an additional step, but it should work across sqlite and PostgreSQL. My recommendation, though, would be to look into using PostgreSQL in development to avoid other hiccups like this.

Comment: I ended up fixing this by creating a SQL view to summarize the data without affecting type cast